# UIImagePNGRepresentation and hex representation of an image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

suppose, I've got a `png` image `A.png`.

Then I add this image to asset catalog in my app, use it at scale 1.

Now, I write the following code:

```
    let im = UIImage(named: "TestByteSet")
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(im!)
    print("\(data)")
```

Meanwhile, I open the original file `A.png` in a hex-viewer.

The question is: am I supposed to see the same data?

I can see that the beginning is clearly the same, which is not surprising: `png` specification tells we have to have png signature at the beginning of the file. However, after some number of bytes data is different.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PNG file can vary significantly depending on how it is encoded and compressed, so what you see is quite normal.

Comment: OK, thanks @user3441734. I you want, please write a separate answer so that I could accept it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG file can vary significantly depending on how it is encoded and compressed, so what you see is quite normal